# How come my UINavigationBar won't animate?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to get my app working so that in the root view controller, no navigation bar is visible, and when I push another view controller onto my stack (using Storyboard segues), the navigation bar animates into view (fades into view as the view slides into view).

As recommended in other SO articles, I have the following in my root controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

The navigation bar does appear/disappear correctly, it just doesn't animate (fade in/out).

I am using a black translucent bar, but I've tried all types of bar and there's no difference. This is on an iPhone app. I've tried also simulator and non-simulator. Any ideas?

I have now created a video showing a demonstration of what my app is doing:

http://youtu.be/B9fuCc2Jqtg

So just to be clear, it IS appearing and disappearing properly, but it happens suddenly. I am trying to get it to fade in/out during this transition.

I've now added a link to my demo project in Xcode 4 / iOS 5.1:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mwsgjyup4iumy2r/QNN7xkHXSt

**UPDATE/ANSWER:** Ultimately it turns out that my code is "working," in that it is doing what Apple intended, animating the navigation bar sliding into view. I was under the false impression that it should also be fading the navigation bar from invisible to visible at the same time, but that is not how it works.

Thanks to @E. Lüders for animation code that shows how to do what I had intended.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. It just looks like in your video and this is the way it happens with animated = YES. How exactly do you want to fade your navigationbar? The alpha value?

Comment: I edited my answer below and added a fade in/out animation

Comment: Probably it would make more sense to use 'viewDidAppear'. Not a good idea starting an animation from within another animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just implemented this testcode and it works fine. In my Storyboard the navigationbar is visible.

```
//  ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end


//  ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Hide navigationbar on view load
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@end


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This controller gets pushed                              //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//  ViewController2.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
@end


//  ViewController2.m
#import "ViewController2.h"
@implementation ViewController2
@end
```

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want a fade in/out effect on the navigation bar change the above code to this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.0f;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 1.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}
```

Comment: I started a new project, used the exact code you have above, and I'm still having the problem. I'm wondering if this could be a bug in the iOS 6 SDK or Xcode 4.5? I'm going to try and find a release version of Xcode 4 / iOS 5 and see if it's OK there.

Comment: I added a video demo showing what my app is doing (I am reproducing this in iOS 5.1 as well): http://youtu.be/B9fuCc2Jqtg

Comment: Added a link to my demo project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mwsgjyup4iumy2r/QNN7xkHXSt

Comment: Thank you for your help. I guess I was thinking the "animate = YES" would not slide the bar into view, but also fade it into view since it's not visible on screen. I tried your fading code, but the effect doesn't really work because the background color it's fading in from is black. If it was transparent, it would work great. I am marking yours as the answer, but let me know if you have any ideas on how to get the fading to happen with the background transparent?

Comment: I take back what I just wrote... this works perfectly! I initially tested it in my "test app," and it didn't behave as I was expected. I moved the code into my real app, and it works exactly as I had intended. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting Hidden you could set the Alpha to 0 in an animation block before hiding it.

Something like that:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //fade Animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    self.navigationController.view.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't seem to work. I think you had a typo and set self.navigationController.view.alpha = 0 rather than self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0. I tried both ways, and it doesn't do what I'm talking about.

Comment: I see now that your code is very similar to @E. Lüders, thanks to you both for your help.